# Specular and diffused reflections

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

reflectivity of a mirror is very high but on a microscopic level no mirror is perfectly smooth so all the reflections must be diffused and we should not see any perfect reflection so how do we see such perfect reflections

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

an optical mirror is flat and smooth *on the scale length of the wavelength of visible light*. imperfections smaller than that do not matter.